# How do I convert a list containing strings and numbers to a list containing strings and integers?

Tags: python

I have a list containing numbers and strings. I want to convert the list without changing the positions of values into a list containing integers and strings. For example:
['840', 'AB', '42', '200', 'BE', '54', '1000']
to be converted into:
[840, 'AB', 42, 200, 'BE', 54, 1000]

Comment: Don't create links to images. Directly upload the image if you want  or copy paste the code. People may fear to click the links

Comment: Please, don't upload images unless they show something really difficult to convey in words. Write your example input and desired output in [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

isdigit() method returns if the string contains only integers or not.
You can achieve what you want by looping through the list and check each element.

Reference: [https://appdividend.com/2022/03/15/how-to-check-if-string-is-integer-in-python/#:~:text=To%20check%20if%20a%20string,string%20are%20digits%20or%20not](https://appdividend.com/2022/03/15/how-to-check-if-string-is-integer-in-python/#:%7E:text=To%20check%20if%20a%20string,string%20are%20digits%20or%20not).

Answer (score 1):

Could you use this?

```
def convert_values(array):
    for idx in range(len(array)):
        if array[idx].lstrip('-').isnumeric(): # remove leading '-' for negatives 
            array[idx] = int(array[idx])
    return array
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension will do it for you.

```
mylist = ['4', 'text', 'string', '55', '67', '8']
my_int_list = [int(value) if value.isdigit() else value for value in mylist]
```

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking. OP has a list of strings and wants to convert each item to an integer if it is numeric.

Comment: edited to fix using @Haruka Morishima suggestion.